# Environment specific variables with requirejs

Tags: requirejs

I would like to set a requirejs configuration variable which would be available via `module.config`. 
The optimizer does not seem to pass this through. 
Is this possible, or should I handle this step via my build process.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set it in your config file for a specific module like this and as long as your told `r.js` to use this config file it should work:

```
requirejs.config({

  config: {
    'path/to/myModule': {
      someSetting: 'someSetting'
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution seems to be to be:

1. Create a config file for each environment (eg., `config`, `config-production`)
2. When you want your config, `require('/path/to/config')`
3. When you call r.js, just put in a paths argument (eg., `r.js -o build.js paths.config=config-production`)
4. You now have your production configuration settings